# Return to previous page with refresh data Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

in main page I have a button create post. When I click on it I receive editor. After input of some text I click button savePost. Then post saves to server and return to my main page, but without new post on my wall. I need to refresh that page to see my new post. How can I write code to receive my previous page with my new post on main page after clicking button savePost?

```
        Button savePost = new Button {Text = "Save post"};
        stackLayout.Children.Add(savePost);
        savePost.Clicked += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var restService = new RestServiceImpl(UserService.User.AccessToken);
            PostView post = new PostView
            {
                Text = textEditor.Text,
            };
            restService.CreatePost(post);
            Navigation.PopAsync();
        };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about it. The most simple one is to implement some mechanism on the `OnAppearing` event of the page and just reload there, or think of some way to detect a reload has to be done instead of just reloading. This can be done for instance by some `bool` you set to true after the 'restService.CreatePost(post);' line.

That kind of brings me to the other way. When you are using some kind of MVVM framework (have a look at [FreshMvvm](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm) for example) you can execute some code when a PageModel is popped. So you have much more granular control over when to reload and detect if it is necessary at all.

A completely other way is to use the [MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/). You can send out a message whenever (and from where ever) reloading is needed and let the pages which needs reloading subscribe to that and execute the reloading code whenever the right message was received.

It all depends on what your requirements and code structure is.

Comment: Thanks for help and very quick answer :)

Comment: If it has helped you (eventually) please don't forget to mark it as the answer!

Comment: By messagecenter I implement live update, Thanks....